# divide an array using a changing length sequence of boolean var as index

Tags: python

i have an array of boolean variables. The array has a sort of structure, it's formed of many sequences of zeros and ones, sequences of different length. such as:

[1111111100001111111111000000000000001111111000000111111111111111110000]

"commas omitted between values"

i need to separate it in this way

[111111110000],[111111111100000000000000],[1111111000000],[111111111111111110000]

Someone knows a good way or just a way to do this ?

Algorithm could be language free, but in case you know how to do it in python you are welcome.

After some struggling i found a way to divide the array, but only if it begins with ONES. I realy can't figure out how to make it work with array beginning with 1 or 0.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

c = 1

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == 1:
        if c == 0:
            print "\n\tDIVIDE\n"
            c = 1
        print "one"

    else:
        if c == 1:
            c = 0
        print "zero"
```

Comment: The answer provided still gives you the information you need, but your question doesn't quite state what you intend to do when the array leads with `0`. Do you then want all the result arrays to lead with `0`, or do you want the first array to only have `0`?

Comment: i read the first element of the array and i set a variables, say START to -1 if it starts with 1 or START=1 if array starts with 0. Then i only need to check condition np.diff(x) == START.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the indices, where you want to split:

```
>>> np.diff(x)
array([ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,
        0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0])
```

Every `1` denotes the change from `0` to `1`.

Apply it (shifted by one index of course):

```
>>> np.split(x, np.nonzero(np.diff(x) == 1)[0]+1)
[array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: Great! You made clear the difference between a real programmer, you, and a human scripter , me.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to upvote, but my reputation is sitll 6. I can't sorry.